# Google Maps multiple marker with info window in angular 7

Tags: angular, google-maps

Hello guys I am new with Angular and I have no idea how to implement Google Maps in Angular. I searched a lot but did not find any good source. Can anybody do that how to implement Google Maps multiple marker with information window in Angular? I have provided some code. Can you guys implement this in Angular? I need help. I can't do this with myself.

```
        var map;
        var InforObj = [];
        var centerCords = {
            lat: -25.344,
            lng: 131.036
        };
        var markersOnMap = [{
                placeName: "Australia (Uluru)",
                LatLng: [{
                    lat: -25.344,
                    lng: 131.036
                }]
            },
            {
                placeName: "Australia (Melbourne)",
                LatLng: [{
                    lat: -37.852086,
                    lng: 504.985963
                }]
            },
            {
                placeName: "Australia (Canberra)",
                LatLng: [{
                    lat: -35.299085,
                    lng: 509.109615
                }]
            }
        ];

        window.onload = function () {
            initMap();
        };

        function addMarkerInfo() {
            for (var i = 0; i < markersOnMap.length; i++) {
                var contentString = '<div id="content"><h1>' + markersOnMap[i].placeName +
                    '</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix mutat posse suscipit id, vel ea tantas 
                omittam detraxit.</p></div>';

                const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: markersOnMap[i].LatLng[0],
                    map: map
                });

                const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString,
                    maxWidth: 200
                });

                marker.addListener('click', function () {
                    closeOtherInfo();
                    infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
                    InforObj[0] = infowindow;
                });
                // marker.addListener('mouseover', function () {
                //     closeOtherInfo();
                //     infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
                //     InforObj[0] = infowindow;
                // });
                // marker.addListener('mouseout', function () {
                //     closeOtherInfo();
                //     infowindow.close();
                //     InforObj[0] = infowindow;
                // });
            }
        }
        function closeOtherInfo() {
            if (InforObj.length > 0) {
                InforObj[0].set("marker", null);
                InforObj[0].close();
                InforObj.length = 0;
            }
        }

        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 4,
                center: centerCords
                center: centerCords
            });
            addMarkerInfo();
        }
```

How can I use above code in Angular any one how can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the guide I used to get started. https://dev.to/devpato/setup-google-maps-with-agm-in-angular-app-33em  I found the easiest way to add multiple markers was to use an ngFor loop with the agm-marker element.

```
<agm-map #gm [latitude]="repo.lat" [longitude]="repo.lng" [(fitBounds)]="repo.bounds" [zoom]="repo.zoom"
(mapReady)="mapReady($event)" (click)="mapClick(gm, $event)">
<agm-marker *ngFor="let mark of markers" [latitude]="mark.latitude"
    [longitude]="mark.longitude" [label]="mark.label" [iconUrl]="mark.markerIconPath"
    (markerClick)="showInfoWindow(infoWindow, gm)" [openInfoWindow]="false">
    <agm-info-window [disableAutoPan]="true" #infoWindow (infoWindowClose)="infoWindowClosed(gm)">

     ... Html for my info window omitted for brevity.
    </agm-info-window>
  </agm-marker>
```

Also I have some special code that closes any open info windows before opening another. That is why I disable the standard "openInfoWindow" directive and add a markerClick handler.

Hope this helps.